# Definition of Internal Direct Sum of Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Here is the definition of an internal direct sum of modules:

> An R-Module $M$ is the internal direct sum of submodules $M_1, M_2$ if:
>
> $a)$ $M=M_1+M_2$
>
> $b)$ $M_1 \cap  M_2 = \{0\}$

I am trying to prove using this definition that $R/I\cong J_{1}/I \oplus J_{2}/I$ iff $R=J_1+J_2$ and $J_1 \cap  J_2 = I$.

Comment: I  suppose you mean $J_1\cap J_2=I$?

Comment: @Bernard My bad. That is totally what I meant. Anyway, I feel like the first direction holds by definition of internal direct sums.

Comment: Yes. Note that this result is an abstract version of the *Chinese remainder theorem*.

Comment: @Bernard Should I use the map $\phi: R\to R/J_{1}\oplus R/J_{2}$ and apply the first isomorphism for rings and use the fact that $J_{1}\cap J_{2}=I$? However, this doesn't make sense to me because I thought the direct sum of submodules look like $J_{1}/I\oplus J_{2}/I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that by assumptions the direct sum $J_1/I \oplus J_2/I$ is well defined. Let $\phi: J_1/I \to J_2/I \to R/I$ defined by $\phi(j_1+I,j_2+I)=j_1+j_2+I$. Then it is easy to check that $\phi$ is well-defined and is surjective since $R=J_1+J_2$, so we are left to prove $\phi$ is injective.

Assume $\phi(j_1+I,j_2+I)=0+I$, this is equivalent $j_1+j_2 \in I$. But $I \subset J_1$ so, $j_1+j_2 \in J_1$, so $j_2 \in J_1$. As $j_2 \in J_2$, we get $j_2 \in J_1 \cap J_2=I$. Thus, $j_2+I=0+I$. A similar argument shows $j_1+I=0$, so $\phi$ is injective.